# Should [cocos2d-x-3.0] be replaced as [cocos2d-x-3.x]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

Now what I found is it has [cocos2d-x-2.x] but it has no [cocos2d-x-3.x] tag, should [cocos2d-x-3.x] be use instead of [cocos2d-x-3.0]?

Also what I was another concerning about is some bug of cocos2d-x may be version specific,e.g.(only appear in version 2.1.4 or 3.4), is it enough to tag it as [cocos2d-x-2.x] for 2.1.4? Also is it necessary to create tag synonyms for different versions such as cocos2d-x-2.2,cocos2d-x-3.4...?

Another minor concern, for other versions,e.g.:4.0 beta, is it use [cocos2d-x] is enough?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a breakdown of all tags matching the filter `[*cocos*]`.

[cocos2d-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d-android) **Q:** 348
[cocos2d-extensions-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d-extensions-ios) **Q:** 3
[cocos2d-html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d-html5) **Q:** 61
[cocos2d-iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d-iphone) **Q:** 10,390
[cocos2d-iphone-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d-iphone-2.x) **Q:** 15
[cocos2d-iphone-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d-iphone-3) **Q:** 31
[cocos2d-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d-js) **Q:** 234
[cocos2d-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d-python) **Q:** 25
[cocos2d-swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d-swift) **Q:** 17
[cocos2d-x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d-x) **Q:** 3,124
[cocos2d-x-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d-x-2.x) **Q:** 86
[cocos2d-x-3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d-x-3.0) **Q:** 567
[cocos2d-x-for-xna](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d-x-for-xna) **Q:** 9
[cocos2d-x-win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d-x-win32) **Q:** 4
[cocos3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos3d) **Q:** 172
[cocosbuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocosbuilder) **Q:** 57
[cocossharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocossharp) **Q:** 4
[cocostudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocostudio) **Q:** 16

The following tags can all be synonymed to [cocos2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d) (which doesn't exist for some reason) because they are all library + lang / platform tags, and you can search for ( [platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/platform) || [language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language) ) + [cocos2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d) and get results relevant to your query.

[cocos2d-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d-android) **Q:** 348
[cocos2d-extensions-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d-extensions-ios) **Q:** 3
[cocos2d-html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d-html5) **Q:** 61
[cocos2d-iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d-iphone) **Q:** 10,390
[cocos2d-iphone-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d-iphone-2.x) **Q:** 15
[cocos2d-iphone-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d-iphone-3) **Q:** 31
[cocos2d-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d-js) **Q:** 234
[cocos2d-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d-python) **Q:** 25
[cocos2d-swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d-swift) **Q:** 17
[cocossharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocossharp) **Q:** 4
[cocostudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocostudio) **Q:** 16

This would leave us with the following tags.

[cocos2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d) **Q:** 11,144
[cocos2d-x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d-x) **Q:** 3,124 (there is no language/platform tag for [x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x))
[cocos2d-x-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d-x-2.x) **Q:** 86
[cocos2d-x-3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d-x-3.0) **Q:** 567
[cocos3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos3d) **Q:** 172
[cocosbuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocosbuilder) **Q:** 57

Then yes, I would say that to keep consistent [cocos2d-x-3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d-x-3.0) should be renamed to [cocos2d-x-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d-x-3.x).

**Note:** I don't actually have any experience with this library, so I don't know if this might break anyone else's work-flow, but I don't see any reason to use [library-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/library-language) tags when not absolutely necessary because, as I said earlier in this post, the library tag can be combined with the language / platform tag to get results relevant to your query.